# GUI testing framework for JavaFX 2

Tags: testing, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, gui-testing

I'm currently reading the book [Growing Object-Oriented Software Guided by Tests](http://growing-object-oriented-software.com/) which gives a decent introduction into test driven development.

One drawback is that the code developed through the book is based on Swing. For my next project I'd like to use Java FX 2 and I'm wondering if there are any GUI testing frameworks out there for it? The book introduces [windowlicker](http://code.google.com/p/windowlicker/), which allows testing Swing applications only.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is a library named JemmyFX. [Jemmy](http://java.net/projects/jemmy/sources/jemmy3/show) itself is a set of libraries and tools to test UI applications (mostly Java-based: Swing, AWT, SWT; but it's being extended to native right now). JemmyFX covers JavaFX for that matter.

JemmyFX can be downloaded as a part of [the test branch of OpenJFX 2](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/2.1/master/tests/) (open-sourced part of JavaFX).

For **JavaFX 8**, [the test branch](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/tests/) includes support for new controls and other fixes.

Comment: Thanks. But as far as I can see it's for Java FX 1.x not Java FX 2.x.

Comment: there is a library for both of them! Take a look at bottom link.

Comment: Note, that JemmyFX is a supported and developed project, and it has its own tag on stackoverflow : "jemmy", you can file issues on it in javafx-jira under jemmy project, and if you wish additional features, you can suggest them.

Answer (score 22):

There's yet another new testing library for JavaFX called [TestFX](https://github.com/SmartBear/TestFX).

Comment: I've started using it and it is significantly easier to use than JemmyFX - Thanks for the good work!

Comment: We had massively used JemmyFx in the past and we are now switching to TestFX. It is far superior IMHO. It is really simpler (Bye bye `Dock`, `Wrap`, `Parent`...)  and nicely integrated with junit. I wrote also some headless test using `Monocle` and it works well too.

Comment: I just created a stackoverflow tag for [tesfx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/testfx)

Answer (score 6):

There's a new test robot called [MarvinFX](http://www.guigarage.com/2013/03/introducing-marvinfx/):

> MarvinFX has the goal to easily test JavaFX controls and scenes with a special attention on properties.

This [other post](http://www.guigarage.com/2013/03/assertions-and-rules-in-marvinfx/) shows how to use assertions and rules with MarvinFX.

Answer (score 5):

Another library (which I have not used or tested) is [TestComplete](http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/30971/).

Answer (score 5):

[Automaton](https://github.com/renatoathaydes/Automaton) is another testing library for JavafX and Swing GUIs born out of the same team that did [TestFX](https://github.com/SmartBear/TestFX)

> - easy tests for Swing and JavaFX applications
> - written for testers. Only basic coding skills required.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Eclipse site](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/category/free-tagging/gui-testing), the modern testing tools for JavaFX in the year 2015 are [Squish](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/squish-automated-cross-platform-cross-technology-eclipse-gui-testing-tool) and [Jubula](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/jubula-automated-functional-testing-standalone-version) . But Squish is commercial. And Jubula is partly free - JavaFX belongs to that free part. And in the Eclipse Mars version already exists the testing distribution. Uses Jubula for UI testing.

Answer (score 1):

Jubula is now totally free, and does indeed support JavaFX.