# How to create Splash screen with transparent background in JavaFX

Tags: java, transparency, javafx-2, javafx, splash-screen

I am trying to create a splash screen like the example I've provded.
It seems that AnchorPane does not allow transparent background, I've tried setting the css of the `AnchorPane` to `-fx-background-color: rgba(255,0,255,0.1) ;` but the white background still shows up.

All I have in my fxml file is a AnchorPane with ImageView with contain the png image

[image: Example]

I've looked everywhere but can't find any solution, any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try this [JavaFX splash sample](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/1588531) created for the Stackoverflow question: [Designing a splash screen (java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9997509/designing-a-splash-screen-java).  And a [follow up sample](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/2305098) which also provides application initialization progress feedback.

JavaFX does offer the [Preloader](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/preloaders.htm) interface for smooth transfer from splash to application, but the above samples don't make use of it.

The splash samples above also don't do the transparent effect, but this [dialog sample](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/1887631) shows you how to do that and you can combine it with the previous splash samples to get the effect you want.

The transparent effect is created by:

1. `stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT)`.
2. `scene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT)`.
3. Ensuring your root node is not an opaque square rectangle.

Which is all demonstrated in Sergey's sample.

Related question:

- [How to use javaFX Preloader with stand-alone application in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15126210/how-to-use-javafx-preloader-with-stand-alone-application-in-eclipse)

*Update Apr 2016 based on additional questions*

> the preloader image isnt in the foreground. I have tried stage.toFront(), but doesnt help.

A new API was created in Java 8u20 [stage.setAlwaysOnTop(true)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#setAlwaysOnTop-boolean-).  I updated the [linked sample](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/2305098) to use this on the initial splash screen, which helps aid in a smoother transition to the main screen.

*For Java8+*

For modena.css (the default JavaFX look and feel definition in Java 8), a slight shaded background was introduced for all controls (and also to panes if a control is loaded).

You can remove this by specifying that the default background is transparent. This can be done by adding the following line to your application's CSS file:

```
.root { -fx-background-color: transparent; }
```

If you wish, you can use CSS style classes and rules or a setStyle call (as demonstrated in Sergey's answer) to ensure that the setting only applies to the root of your splash screen rather than all of your app screens.

See related:

- [how to make transparent scene and stage in javafx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34033119/how-to-make-transparent-scene-and-stage-in-javafx)

Comment: Thanks guys! Both answer are good but `scene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT).` you don't need to specify the width and height of the scene

Comment: I was experiencing a milisecond-flick with background visible when the stage was shown. I managed to solve this issue by calling: 
`root.setCache(true); root.setCacheHint(CacheHint.SPEED);` _(where root is Parent instance)_.

Comment: When I use stage.initStyle(Transparent), the preloader image isnt in the foreground. I have tried stage.toFront(), but doesnt help. If I switch back to undecorated, it works fine. Any ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work. I'm using Java 8u66.

Answer (score 14):

You need to have transparent `Stage` and `Scene` for that. `Pane` itself doesn't have a color.

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Button btn = new Button("Say 'Hello World'");

    AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane();
    root.getChildren().add(btn);

    // Java 8: requires setting the layout pane background style to transparent
    // https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8092764
    // "Modena uses a non-transparent background by default"
    root.setStyle("-fx-background-color: transparent;"); 

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250, Color.TRANSPARENT);
    primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: how will i unit test this. I simply tried to unit test this but it shows not on fx application thread error.

Comment: @vinay take a look at next questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11385604/how-do-you-unit-test-a-javafx-controller-with-junit and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10599724/gui-testing-framework-for-javafx-2/10600676