# Cannot set style once stage has been set visible

Tags: javafx

i have a stage and set it's style to

```
stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
```

after some seconds i need to change initStyle to Decorate but when i use

```
stage.initStyle(StageStyle.Decorate );
```

give me this exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot set style once stage has been set visible
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**What Not to Do**

As the exception says, you

> Cannot set style once stage has been set visible

So, if you can't do that, don't try to do it.

**What to Do**

Instead, hide your transparent stage and create a new stage with the new style.
When doing so, be careful because the default behaviour is to shut down the JavaFX system once all stages have been hidden.  To avoid this either switch off the default behaviour and explicitly shutdown the JavaFX system when needed or ensure that you always have at least one Window visible.

**Example**

```
// initialize your splash stage.
Platform.setImplicitExit(false);
splashStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
. . .
// create your main stage.
Stage mainStage = new Stage();
mainStage.setScene(mainScene);
mainStage.initStyle(StageStyle.DECORATED); 
mainStage.setOnHide(event -> Platform.exit())
. . .
// on some later event hide your splash stage and show your main stage.
splashStage.hide();
mainStage.show();
```

**Related**

Here is a [full executable sample](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/1588531) based on an answer to a previous question => [How to create Splash screen with transparent background in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14972199/how-to-create-splash-screen-with-transparent-background-in-javafx).