# making javafx application fade over a period

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

i need to create a java notification that once show fades over time and then is destroyed, but if the user mouses over it it should become alive. I essentially need to set the transparency of the entire notification (background, labels and image views) over a period to fully transparent. I've searched the web and can't find a straightforward way to do it in javafx any help?

Comment: Combine Deepanshu's answer to fade on the root node with a mouse listener to stop fading and a [transparent scene background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14972199/how-to-create-splash-screen-with-transparent-background-in-javafx) so the app can truly "disappear".  Give it a go and see how far you get.

Answer (score 1):

Read about transition [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/animations/basics.htm).

Example on how to achieve fading here:

```
 final Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(10, 10, 100, 100);
 rect1.setArcHeight(20);
 rect1.setArcWidth(20);
 rect1.setFill(Color.RED);
 ...
 FadeTransition ft = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(3000), rect1);
 ft.setFromValue(1.0);
 ft.setToValue(0.1);
 ft.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
 ft.setAutoReverse(true);
 ft.play();
```

Comment: this is only for node objects how do i apply it to stages and popups? thanks in advance

Comment: more examples are in the link. it will explain how to apply it to stages and popups and accept my answer :P.@user3619109