# JavaFX Preloader splashscreen not working when launched with install4j

Tags: javafx-8, splash-screen, install4j, preloader

I have added a splash screen to my standalone JavaFX application (Java 8), using the Preloader api.

Everything works fine from the IDE and when running the packaged jar from the command line.

However, when I run from an install4j launcher, the splash screen is not shown.
I am able to see the application icon in the taskbar when the splash screen is supposed to show, then it disappears briefly, to reappear again when the app is finally shown.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the JavaFX preloader with the JavaFX DataApp sample application:

https://github.com/ingokegel/javafx-dataapp-sample

See [this commit](https://github.com/ingokegel/javafx-dataapp-sample/commit/2645dd74baf63f45c837e1e37f9126dd891585b3) for instructions on how to build the install4j project.

I can see the preloader. Please check it out and investigate how your project is different from the JavaFX DataApp sample application.

Comment: My project differed from your example, as it is a stand alone application. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by the parameter -Dprism.order=sw that I was using from the installer. After removing that VM parameter, the preloader workded fine.

My project is a standalone application, where Preloader doesn't add much benefits, and I do need to disable hardware acceleration, so I ended replacing preloader with a simple stage and initialization done in another thread, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14973758/666228).